# Angular application in development mode stopped working

Tags: angular, runtime-error

My application suddenly crashed and unable to work on localhost:4200, I am completely clueless where the fault is:

tried using `npm run build:ssr`

```
ERROR Unknown Error

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Unknown Error
    at resolvePromise (/Users/vinni/Projects/HRMS/admin/hrms/dist/hrms-admin/server/main.js:106508:39)
    at resolvePromise (/Users/vinni/Projects/HRMS/admin/hrms/dist/hrms-admin/server/main.js:106460:21)
    at /Users/vinni/Projects/HRMS/admin/hrms/dist/hrms-admin/server/main.js:106570:21
    at ZoneDelegate.crGB.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (/Users/vinni/Projects/HRMS/admin/hrms/dist/hrms-admin/server/main.js:106097:35)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (/Users/vinni/Projects/HRMS/admin/hrms/dist/hrms-admin/server/main.js:143463:33)
    at ZoneDelegate.crGB.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (/Users/vinni/Projects/HRMS/admin/hrms/dist/hrms-admin/server/main.js:106096:40)
    at Zone.crGB.Zone.runTask (/Users/vinni/Projects/HRMS/admin/hrms/dist/hrms-admin/server/main.js:105864:51)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (/Users/vinni/Projects/HRMS/admin/hrms/dist/hrms-admin/server/main.js:106277:39)
    at crGB.ZoneTask.invokeTask (/Users/vinni/Projects/HRMS/admin/hrms/dist/hrms-admin/server/main.js:106183:25)
    at Timeout.ZoneTask.invoke (/Users/vinni/Projects/HRMS/admin/hrms/dist/hrms-admin/server/main.js:106168:52) {
  rejection: 'Unknown Error',
  promise: ZoneAwarePromise [Promise] {
    __zone_symbol__state: 0,
    __zone_symbol__value: 'Unknown Error'
  },
  zone: <ref *1> Zone {
    _parent: Zone {
      _parent: null,
      _name: '<root>',
      _properties: {},
      _zoneDelegate: [ZoneDelegate]
    },
    

Unknown Error
```

I tried to rebuild but as soon as the url is going to access, this error is coming.

Comment: Did you try restarting the server? Also, can you create a Stackblitz example?

Comment: So if I am not wrong , you did build using `npm run build:ssr` and trying to access application using `localhost:4200` ?

Comment: @Rajat already done.

Comment: @PiyushJain yes, as always. this application is running on the port from so long. So nothing to worry from port point of view.

Comment: `npm run build: ssr` is not for dev, if you want to run your app in dev mode, use this `npm run dev:ssr`

If you want to run your app in prod mode then run `npm run build: ssr`, it will generate a dist folder then you have to run genrated files using `http-server` npm module.

Comment: as I stated earlier, it is running fine in more than 4 apps and from last 6 months so there is nothing wrong with the code. i know npm run build: ssr I using this just to build the project. Well I restarted the computer and it sarted working. Don't know what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the dist folder. So please delete the dist folder and then build again.

[dist folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmWHv.png)